# Component losing received props upon refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I have one component which has a list of items, and depending on which item the user taps on, this takes them into a second component which renders information based on the props it received from the previous component.

In the second component, I have an API call based on the props received from the previous component, which is called once the component mounts.

```
async getItem() {
    let req = await fetch(API_URL + '/items/item/' + this.props.location.itemID)
    let response = await req.json()
    // Does other things
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getItem()
  }
```

My problem is that if the user refreshes the second component, there is an Unhandled Rejection because the second component has no idea what the itemID prop is or where the user "refreshed" from.
Without re-architecting the whole thing, how do I handle this?

If it matters, I use `react-router-dom` and pass the props via a `to=` prop, like so `to={{pathname: '/item', itemID: item.id}}`

Comment: What router are you using? How does your url looks like once you hit that component?

Comment: you could store the itemId in localStorage, and when mounting the component, if props are not defined, you could load them from localStorage (reupdating the state properly from the parent or whoever is the owner). If it is undefined too, then it is an exception

Comment: @Icepickle As mentioned, I am using `react-router-dom` which is defined elsewhere like this `<Route path='/item' component={Item} />`. Are you suggesting I append the required details onto the path? So if I am going from `/items` to `item/1` it'll use that instead of the prop?

Comment: @user3328696 yes, cause otherwise you would have to restore that state from somewhere else, as Gonzalo said